# Prettier Code Formatter for VS code fails with 'No loader specified for extension ".cjs"'

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

In VS Code, When I select `Format Document With...` then choose `Prettier - Code Formatter`, I get the following error:

```
Command 'Format Document' resulted in an error (No loader specified for extension ".cjs", so searchPlaces item ".prettierrc.cjs" is invalid)
```

From what I can gather this has something to do with underlying TypeScript in VS Code not having a loader available for `.cjs` files and Prettier searching for `prettierrc.cjs` but I can't quite see how that all fits together, or how to work around it.

Has anyone else encountered, found a work around or solved this or a similar issue in VS Code?

Comment: I tried disabling the Prettier VS Code extension and enabling it again and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Or try to uninstall the Prettier in Vs Code and then install it again.

Comment: If your issue is solved then please update this post with the answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I tried disabling the Prettier VS Code extension and enabling it again and that fixed the issue for me.

Credits @NikolajDamLarsen

Comment: I had to uninstall the extension completely but this seems to be solving the issue for others.

Comment: To confirm the previous answers, either restarting VSCode or disabling+reloading+reenabling should work (whatever suits one better). Looks like a VSCode bug when specifying the name config file name: it saves the correct name to while forgetting what it saved.